# What is odds against chance fallacy?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

An article[1] about bad statistics in psychology books contains the following sentence:

> The most common misconception identified in the books was the odds-against-chance fallacy (defining statistical significance as a less than a 5% likelihood of a result being random.)

Googling odds-against-chance fallacy just gives gambler's fallacy, but that is not what is discussed here.

[1] Cassidy, S. A., Dimova, R., Giguère, B., Spence, J. R., & Stanley, D. J. (2019)
"Failing Grade: 89% of Introduction-to-Psychology Textbooks That Define or Explain Statistical Significance Do So Incorrectly"
*Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science.*
https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245919858072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read a lot about fallacies in statistical inference and the phrase 'odds-against-chance fallacy' is new to me. The explanation in parentheses does not make matters any clearer.

Possibly the writer is referring to the regrettably very common error in interpreting p-values of tests of a given null hypothesis.

In that context, a p-value of less than 0.05 means that **assuming that the null hypothesis is true** then the probability of getting the result we did (or an even more extreme result) was small. That might make you doubt the truth of the null hypothesis, but it tells you literally nothing about any specific alternative hypothesis - because you have assumed in calculating the p-value that no alternative hypothesis is true.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a formal fallacy as much as it is a common misconception. Many psychology undergraduates (and more graduate students than we might like) interpret p values as something like "the probability that some finding was obtained by chance or random error". For example, let's say some educational intervention increased test scores by 5 points (p = .02). Someone under this misconception would say there is only a 2% chance that we could have obtained this finding by random error of some sort.

Edit:
Actually, it occurred to me that the way I most often hear this (incorrectly) phrased is something like "there is only a 2% chance that my hypothesis that this intervention increases tests scores is wrong".